# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION when creating Price Book Entry from flow

Tags: visual-workflow, error, pricebookentry

I have created a flow that creates a pricebook entry for new products (based on a custom field on the Product object), however when I debug the flow it comes up with the following quite generic error:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: field integrity exception.
```

I cannot work out what I am doing wrong. I have reduced the flow to three steps:

1. Start
2. Assignment: recNewPriceBookEntry
3. CreateRecord (base on reNewPriceBookEntry)

The full output of the final step that causes the error is:

> **FAST CREATE:** Create_New_Price_Book_Entry
>
> Create PricebookEntry records using the values that are stored in {!recNewPriceBookEntry}.
>
> **Variable Values**
>
> [IsActive=true,Product2Id=01t25000003Hfy8,UnitPrice=1200,UseStandardPrice=true,Pricebook2Id=01s58000001nQb8]
>
> **Result**
>
> Failed to create records.
>
> Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: field integrity exception.

I have also tried using the 18 character IDs (01t25000003Hfy8AAC & 01s58000001nQb8AAE), which results in the same error.

As this is a fresh sandbox, there are no entries in the Price Book Entry object (I double checked that with Developer Workbench).

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have multicurrency enabled? Are you sure they are the correct ID values for that org?

Comment: UseStandardPrice field value can not be set to true on insert.

Comment: Removing the UseStandardPrice field from recNewPriceBookEntry solved the problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rohit Patil](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12204/rohit-patil)'s comment solved the problem:

> UseStandardPrice field value can not be set to true on insert.

I removed the UseStandardPrice field from recNewPriceBookEntry and it started working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

came across in a similar problem.

**Findings:**

if we have a `discrepancy` in unitPrice in between standard and custom price book and we are using `UseStandardPrice = true` then we will get the same error as follows:

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION

**to solve the issue:**

we have to maintain the `unitPrice` same as `standard PriceBookEntry`,
then only we can mark the `UseStandardPrice = true`

or we need to mark `UseStandardPrice = false` if we want to insert the record with some different unit price value